# Uploading a file or saving text using GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt

In this site that I'm making, I want the user to upload a file or enter text in a textbox which I shall save in a file. 
For something like below in HTML,

```
<form action="UploadServlet" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="50" /> <br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

I want an equivalent code in java. So I tried the following-

```
FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
FormPanel fp = new FormPanel();
upload.setName("uploader");
fp.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
fp.setVisible(true);
fp.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
fp.setAction("/UploadServlet");
```

The above code in onModuleLoad() alongwith the necessary extra lines for adding the objects in the RootPanel. Yet the code doesn't work. What's wrong?

(UploadServlet.java extends HttpServlet and It stores the file uploaded by the user)

Comment: What does not work? Any exceptions?

Comment: the file doesn't get uploaded by the java code as it got by the html one.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code may help you

```
  final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
  //create a file upload widget
  final FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
  //create labels
  Label selectLabel = new Label("Select a file:");
  //create upload button
  Button uploadButton = new Button("Upload File");
  //pass action to the form to point to service handling file 
  //receiving operation.
  form.setAction("SERVLET PATH");
  // set form to use the POST method, and multipart MIME encoding.
  form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
  form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);

  //add a label
  panel.add(selectLabel);
  //add fileUpload widget
  panel.add(fileUpload);
  //add a button to upload the file
  panel.add(uploadButton);

  uploadButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        //get the filename to be uploaded
        String filename = fileUpload.getFilename();
        if (filename.length() == 0) {
           Window.alert("No File Specified!");
        } else {
           //submit the form
           form.submit();                     
        }               
     }
  });
```